# I am getting "missing keyword" error in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am new to SQL and I am trying to create the table for itinerary items however keep getting the same error message that I am "missing a keyword". I have tried looking it up for what is wrong however I can not find anything

Any solution or if you have any design suggestions to this would be much appreciated!

```sql
create table itinerary_item
( tour_id     varchar(8) 
, location_id varchar(8) 
, order_visited_number varchar(8) 
, primary key (tour_id, location_id) 
, foreign key (tour_id) references tour(tour_id)
, foreign key (location_id) location(location_id)
);
```

Comment: what is the error massage you are getting?

Comment: i keep getting the error message "missing keyword"

Comment: you have missed references keyword in the last line while creating foreign key!!!

Comment: It's 1 am over here so I am probably tired should have seen that easy mistake though. however many thanks my friend your help was much appreciated!

Comment: No worries!!! let me answer the question!!

Comment: When you post an error message, please cut & paste the entire message you get, not just a summary like "missing keyword".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi please use references keyword at the last line of your sql table creation script!!!